# Directive Update then run Query to Update Dom on Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-directive, watch

I've looked at more than 10 different directive questions and none have worked for me thus far. I'm trying to have my controller recognize `site.selectedUnit` has changed which updates selectedChannel in my custom directive. The first time works great, but after that the ng-click does not change the view info. The `selectedChannel` is registered and stored on my chatList controller, but the http requests are not called again.

If i click on a unit in site.html, the selectedChannel for the unit number changes in the chatList view, so I'm guessing the http requests are not being called again.

How do I add a listener to either the directive or my chatList controller so I can call the http requests again when selectedChannel changes?

Comment: You've given us too many fragments and left out key pieces of code like the controller for site.html, the template for the directive ('views/chatList.html').  I think you have more than one issue here like referencing a variable named 'vm' in your controller that has never been defined and using this assignment "controller: 'ChatListController as chatList'" in your directive that should be  "controller: 'ChatListController', controllerAs: 'chatList'".  That's just the obvious stuff without seeing the other pertinent code.  I would suggest setting up and sharing a plunker with your code.

Comment: There is nothing pertinent in my site controller that interacts with the directive other than a http request that populates the units array. I will add the views/chatList.html, but the key issues are in the three listed files. Both "controller: 'ChatListController as ChatList'"  and "controller: 'ChatListController', controllerAs: 'chatList'" work when setting up a directive. I've worked with both.

Comment: Your site controller is pertinent because if site.selectedUnit is declared in the controller you will get different results than if it isn't.

Comment: Also, I went ahead and added var vm = this; Sorry couldn't take entire code or else this question would be enormous and I missed this piece.

Comment: selectedUnit is not declared in the site controller. The first and only instance of it is on the view.

Comment: So then selectedUnit only exists in context with each <a> element and won't be accessible elsewhere

Comment: Correct. When one of the units are selected, it opens a chatList for that specific unit using the selectedChannel which is equal to the site.selectedUnit.  selectedChannel is then used for the http request to generate the view information. The http request is triggered the first time and the chatList view loads correctly. selectedChannel is then updated onclick, but does not do the queries again to reload the view.

Comment: Actually, it won't because site.selectedUnit is undefined outside the context of an individual <a> tag.  So ng-if="site.selectedUnit" will never evaluate as true.

Comment: Are you saying it wont work the second time or wont ever work? The reason I ask is it works the first time as intended, but does not for future attempts

Comment: Correction ... it won't work at all if $scope.site isn't defined in your controller.

Comment: I went ahead and added the site controller with the http request for units.

Comment: Back to my original comment ... when you have this much code that could possibly be related to your issue(s) and you don't provide a plunker or enough working code for someone else (like me) to put together a plunker, then you're probably not going to get the help you need.  Otherwise, its a guessing game where you're expecting someone to ask a bunch of questions (for instance, What is unitChannel that is referenced in ChatListController?) to help you resolve your issue.  Maybe its just me that needs the actual code ... perhaps someone smarter than me can figure it out with what you've shown.

Comment: Sorry unitChannel is just an instantiated variable. that is used to compare previous selectedChannel to current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can tell from the code you've provided, you need to make a few changes

**site.controller**

Add a definition for $scope.site otherwise site.selectedUnit will only be available in the context that it is defined in the HTML via ng-click.

```
$scope.site = {
  selectedUnit: null
};
```

**chatList.directive**

Remove the isolate scope and inject the selectedChannel property via bindToController so that it will be accessible in the controller.

```
.directive('chatList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    bindToController: {
      selectedChannel: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'chatList.html',
    controller: 'ChatListController',
    controllerAs: 'chatList'
  };
})
```

**chatList.controller**

Watch for changes to selectedChannel.id to make your $http.get() call

```
vm.tenants = [];

$scope.$watch(angular.bind(vm.selectedChannel.id, function() {

   // make http.get call here
}))
```

You have other issues as well that are too many to list so here's a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tT5WfOuaTVbr1QVW2YrC?p=preview)

Comment: The $scope.$watch was what I needed. I wasn't sure if I needed that in my directive or controller, but after implementing all of your suggestions, that did the trick. Thanks for all the help. That was a day and a half of work for me to get to that point. I know my post wasn't the easiest to work with, but you really helped me out.